# touchesEnded broke UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uikit

I have an UIButton container implementing :

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

My container have subcontainers and one of them is containing an `UIScrollView`.

But my scroll is broken.

How can I handle my scroll without remove `touchesEnded` method ?

Comment: Is container UIView with touchesEnded method above scroll view?

Comment: No that's the problem

Comment: @Andy I edited my post. Sorry my container is un UIButton. So basically, how pass through UIButton event to achieve my scroll ?

Comment: @Andy I know ... But this is an old project I've got with no choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing the below delegate method:-

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender{
  //executes when you scroll the scrollView
}
```

Inside this method you can set the flag and then the same flag you can check inside `touchesEnded` method to avoid inside written code.